# Sumbit button not working as it should

Tags: javascript, forms, button, submit

Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/uNbYu/1/

If you click submit, the button doesn't do anything, but simply hides the text box and only works the second time.

How can I find a way to fix this problem without removing the `.hide()` in the JS?? As I really need that.

Thanks

EDIT: The text box should be made hidden when the text input is clicked out of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the button doesn't seem to do anything the first time you click it is because you aren't actually clicking it. The blur event on the input field fires first, causing the field to disappear. The result is that your click does not actually land on the button!

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNbYu/10/
In this example, I'm binding the hiding of the input field to the click of the submit button.

I'm not sure if this fully solves your problem. I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want :) Thanks

Comment: Great. Something else to keep in mind when it comes to blur: a blur event will always fire before a focus event as well, just like it fires before the click event.

Answer (score 1):

Your `blur()` function is actually being called when you click the button, which moves the button and missing the click event.

You can see this if you don't click the button, but instead click outside the form input, then click the button. It works.